# Как убрать лишний вывод данных

Tags: list, java

Всем привет, помогите с выводом, что-то не могу додуматься..
Есть ArrayList

```
 List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Дальше в методе находим похожие элементы

```
private void count() {
    for (String arr : array) {
        int count = Collections.frequency(array, arr);
        System.out.println("count - " + arr + " - " + count);
    }
}
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
count "элемент 1" - количество 3
count "элемент 1" - количество 3
count "элемент 2" - количество 5
count "элемент 2" - количество 5
```

Как убрать лишние элементы? Чтобы они здесь не дублировались.. Я думал создать массив из полученныех данных пройтись по ним и сравнивать значения, если будут совпадать то удалять а потом только на вывод, может есть элегантнее решение? Или вообще неправильный ход мыслей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(array);
for (String arr : set) {
    int count = Collections.frequency(array, arr);
    System.out.println("count - " + arr + " - " + count);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду доосмысливать)

Answer (score 0):

Вы ищете частоту всех элементов, в том числе и повторяющихся. Для того что бы получить только уникальные в java есть коллекция - Set. Вот как она решает эту задачу:

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("элемент 1");
array.add("элемент 1");
array.add("элемент 1");
array.add("элемент 2");
array.add("элемент 2");
array.add("элемент 2");
array.add("элемент 2");
array.add("элемент 2");

for (String arr : new HashSet<String>(array)) {
  int count = Collections.frequency(array, arr);
  System.out.println("count - " + arr + " - " + count);
}
```

HashSet<String>(array) - оборачиваем List в Set и получаем только уникальные, а дальше итерируемся по ним и находим частоту.